# Escaping characters on Twig's localized date filter

Tags: symfony, twig, intl

When using the default `date` filter, we can escape characters by using `\\` in front of each character.

The same does not seem to apply when using the `localizeddate` filter ([example](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html)).

Anyone knows a way of escaping characters when using the Intl filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accoring to official [`ICU` docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime), you can escape any letter using single-quote (`'`).

Example format:

```
hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz
```

should produce:

```
12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
```

Notice the `'o''clock'` which does not get tokenized...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [format](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html#arguments) argument. In the last parameter you can escape text with `'`. `''` will produce a real `'`.

```
{{ date|localizeddate('short', 'none', locale, null, 'd/m/y HH:mm') }}
```

Comment: I did use the `format` argument, but was unaware that the single quote could be used to escape chars.